# Get numbers string Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, find

Can anyone help me?

I have this string:

> Tip:1-Cli:337|Neg:695|Pro:7558|Nom:802|Esq:1|Rub:None|Con:None|Emp:None|Com:1,Tip:1-Cli:337|Neg:695|Pro:7558|Nom:850|Esq:1|Rub:None|Con:None|Emp:None|Com:1,Tip:1-Cli:337|Neg:695|Pro:7558|Nom:1627|Esq:1|Rub:None|Con:None|Emp:None|Com:1

I try to get the numbers: "`7558", "7558", "7558" y "802", "850", "1627"`

This is my code:

```
    for y in str(nvaCadena):
         o_pro = nvaCadena.index('Pro:') + 4         
         f_pro = nvaCadena.index('|Nom:')            
         p = nvaCadena[o_pro: f_pro]

         o_nom = nvaCadena.index('|Nom:') + 5
         f_nom = nvaCadena.index('|Esq:')
         n = nvaCadena[o_nom:f_nom]
```

But I get: `7558 - 802 7558 - 802 7558 - 802`

And I want: `7558 - 802 7558 - 850 7558 - 1627`

Please Help!

Comment: Please give a complete example that we can run. Specifically, please show all variable initializations.

Comment: It does not feel like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @DYZ Nor to me.  The linked answer discusses a list and this question says it's a string, so the two problems are not quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and probably should) use regular expressions:

```
numbers = re.findall(r'Pro:(\d+)\|Nom:(\d+)',s)
# [('7558', '802'), ('7558', '850'), ('7558', '1627')]
" ".join((x + " - " + y) for x,y in numbers)
# '7558 - 802 7558 - 850 7558 - 1627'
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer for someone who has mastered regular expressions but is unfamiliar with the basic string manipulation capabilities of the standard library, e.g., the string.find() function.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `nvaCadena` is a list. You should not convert it to a string with `str(nvaCadena)`.

Next, you should use the loop variable `y` instead of ignoring it.

Comment: The question specifically says, "I have this string...".

Comment: @PaulCornelius if `nvaCadena` is already a string, then there is no reason to do `str(nvaCadena)`. Furthermore, your loop incorrect because you ignore`y`. The output you get is because you are doing the exact same thing over and over.